# Why doesn't CopyObject for CloudFlare R2 not work with the AWS SDK for .NET?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloudflare, aws-sdk-net, cloudflare-r2

I'm trying to move my object between two buckets.

I execute a CopyRequest, then a DeleteRequest. But when I'm trying to copy the object, I get the following error:

> Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: Header 'x-amz-tagging-directive' with value 'COPY' not implemented

I tried to remove the header after creating an instance of `CopyObjectRequest`, but there is no header with similar name. Also, I saw no configuration for this when creating a new instance of `CopyObjectRequest`.

```cs
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;

var client = new AmazonS3Client(config);

var request = new CopyObjectRequest
{
    SourceBucket = originBucket,
    SourceKey = fileIdString,
    DestinationBucket = destinationBucket,
    DestinationKey = fileIdString
};

await client.CopyObjectAsync(request);
// deleting object...
```

Comment: ` ❌ x-amz-tagging-directive` as per [CloudFlare docs](https://developers.cloudflare.com/r2/api/s3/api/) so not supported... the .NET SDK will set either `REPLACE`or `COPY` for that header. Can you try adding `TagSet = new List<Tag> { new() { Key = null, Value = null } },` to the `CopyObjectRequest` and see if that works? If not, try `TagSet = new List<Tag> { new() { Key = "", Value = "" } }`.

Comment: Thanks for the help @ErmiyaEskandary, but It didn't work. According to the .NET SDK, there is no way to make it work, x-amz-tagging-directive is always being set. 
I opened an feature request, hope they change it to be optional, since S3 docks already has a default value for x-amz-tagging-directive to be COPY.

Unfortunly for now I have to manually download resource and re-upload to another bucket(which is expensive) until something changes from cloudflare or aws sdk.

Comment: Correct yes - it's actually not AWS's fault here. You need to specify that if an item is being copied - S3 needs to know if you want the the tags copied too or not. CloudFlare should improve their compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10/01/2024: CloudFlare support have confirmed to me that the R2 team have filed an internal ticket to track getting this fixed.

—-

As per [CloudFlare docs](https://developers.cloudflare.com/r2/api/s3/api/), the `x-amz-tagging-directive` header is still not supported:

> ❌ x-amz-tagging-directive

The [`CopyObject`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CopyObject.html#API_CopyObject_RequestSyntax) API itself doesn't *strictly* require the `x-amz-tagging-directive` header as S3 internally defaults to `COPY`; CloudFlare may just do a no-op behind the scenes if the header is not sent.

The .NET SDK does not provide a way of omitting this header. It always sets a value for this header, to determine if the tags for the object need to be copied. Other SDKs I've checked i.e. JS, Java, Python also do the same.

You can see this from the [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/main/sdk/src/Services/S3/Custom/Model/Internal/MarshallTransformations/CopyObjectRequestMarshaller.cs#L77-L85):

```cs
if (copyObjectRequest.IsSetTagSet())
{
    request.Headers.Add(S3Constants.AmzHeaderTagging, AmazonS3Util.TagSetToQueryString(copyObjectRequest.TagSet));
    request.Headers.Add(S3Constants.AmzHeaderTaggingDirective, TaggingDirective.REPLACE.Value);
}
else
{
    request.Headers.Add(S3Constants.AmzHeaderTaggingDirective, TaggingDirective.COPY.Value);
}
```

Unfortunately, until CloudFlare support this header, you need to manually do [`GetObject`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html) & then [`PutObject`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html) in order to copy the object across.

<sup>P.S. I will raise this with CloudFlare support</sup>